# Wrong profile photo when creating account

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts, profile-picture

So when I created my account, it showed me an option to pick my username, profile photo (Google or generated), topics I'm interested, job opportunities, etc. I chose to use the generated profile photo, but when I created the account, it gave me the Google one, basically discarding my choice within the account creation screen. I had to manually change it afterwards. It's not like it's difficult to workaround this bug but fixing it wouldn't hurt.